# Binding does not work in Angular after call function from another component

Tags: angular, binding

I have two components the navigation component that is the navigation menu of the app, and the home component.
I make a call from home component to a function in the navigation component. The call succeds and changes a public property of the navigation component. This public property is bound in the html template. But although the property changes the value in the html remains the same, that is the binding does not work.
Some code for you:

`navigation.component.html`:

```html
<a href="">
    <img style="cursor:pointer" src="../assets/pics/cart.jpg" />
    <span id="CartTotal">{{cartTotal| currency: 'EUR'}}</span>
</a>
```

Here see the binding with the property `cartTotal`

code of the function of the navigation component that updates this property and gets called from the home component:

`navigation.component.ts`:

```js
public getCartTotal() {    
    var url = this.baseUrl + "api/Ajax/GetCart";
    this.http.get<CartViewModel>(url).subscribe(res => { 
       console.log(res); 
       this.cartTotal = res.total }, 
       error => console.error(error));
}
```

and finally what I wrote in the home component to call the function of the navigation component:
`home.component.ts`:

```js
import { NavMenuComponent } from '../nav-menu/nav-menu.component';

@Component({
  providers: [NavMenuComponent],
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private navmenu: NavMenuComponent, 
              private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,
              private router:Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

// snip --

  AddToCart(productId, qty: number) {
    var cartlineReqModel: CartLineRequestModel = <CartLineRequestModel>{};
    cartlineReqModel.productId = productId;
    cartlineReqModel.quantity = qty;
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/ajax/AddToCart', cartlineReqModel).subscribe(
      result => { console.log(result); this.navmenu.getCartTotal() },
      error => console.error(error))
  }

 // enter code here

}
```

the code of the `navigation.component.ts` is very simple, here it is for those who asked:

```js
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit{
  isExpanded = false;
  cartTotal: number = 0;
  constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string, private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCartTotal();
  }

  public getCartTotal() {

    var url = this.baseUrl + "api/Ajax/GetCart";
    this.http.get<CartViewModel>(url).subscribe(res => { 
        console.log(res); 
        this.cartTotal = res.total }, 
        error => console.error(error));
   }

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of the navigation component?

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, does that work if you add this in the subscribe handler of `getCartTotal`:  `setTimeout(() =>this.cartTotal = res.total)`

Comment: i added the code of the navigation component

Comment: Do you use the `nav.component` inside the `home.component.html`? if so I would opt to use a `@ViewChild` query selector or more favorably a `service`. Furthermore does the `console.log` inside cart total work and does it trigger?

Comment: may be update zone.js dependency using `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` this will update UI after property value gets changed.

Comment: The navigation component is not a child of the home component. the console.log works and triggers inside the cart total function

Comment: DId you try with the setTimeout ?

Comment: I tried with Settimeout but to no avail

Comment: @Gaurang where should i make this change?

Comment: first constructor of home component add dependency `constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)` then , when after you have changed any property from component just called `this.cdr.detectChanges()` .

Comment: I tried the detectchanges but it does not work unfortunately

Comment: If i put a button in the navigation menu: <button (click)="getCartTotal()">refresh</button>
it works

Comment: can you please make stackblitz demo here?

Comment: and put `detectChanges()` into the navigation component of `getCartTotal()`.

Comment: @Gaurang i tried detectchanges there too. It just does not work

Comment: You cannot inject `NavMenuComponent`  in home component's constructor - pretty sure its not added to providers array, so you are not getting the instance of `NavMenuComponent` you're seeing in your app

Comment: I think the problem is I am changing another instance of navigation component, not the one that is displayed.

Comment: @julius right, that's what i was just thinking. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Use a service to communicate between components

Comment: I am pretty novice to angular. I cannot write such service, I fear..

Comment: @Julius can you post some code that gets me started with writing the service?

Comment: angular.io has quite good documentation on how to write services

Comment: Your really should use a service. Communication between components is one of the main reasons why services exist in angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working demo in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbjmgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.ts) ( with or without parent-child ).

Working Demo in this [StackBLitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbjmgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts) ( With sibling router-outlet ).

Working demo in this [StackBLitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fy2fcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation%2Fnavigation.component.ts) ( Using Serivce Communication ).

First of all you need `template-reference variable` defined in `navigation-component`. so our parent component be like this...

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navigation #appNav>
  <app-home [nav]="appNav"></app-home>
</app-navigation>
```

In above code, `<app-home>` is defined under `<app-navigation>`. and this is called content-projection. Note here, `#appNav` is template-reference variable. `appNav` is passed as input to `<app-home>` component so that navigation component same instance we can get from home component too.

**home.component.html**

```
<button (click)="updateNav()">Update Nav</button>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent {
  @Input('nav') appNav;
  updateNav(){
    this.appNav.getTotal(2);
  }
}
```

Note, above `@Input()` is getting navigation component reference, and we will update value of navigation component property using `updateNav()` method.

**navigation.component.html**

```
<div>
  <span>{{total}}</span>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**navigation.componenet.ts**

```
export class NavigationComponent {
  total = 0;
  getTotal(totall?: number){
    console.log(totall);
    this.total = totall;
    console.log(this.total);
  }
}
```

Note, above `getTotal()` method is called from `home.ts` using `updateNav()` method and this method called and updating value directly provided by home component.

Hope, everything is worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but does this work for sibling components? The navigation and the home component are siblings. Also the home component is taken from router outlet.

Comment: Yes this works for sibling component too. just changed `app.component.html` to `<app-navigation #appNav>
</app-navigation>
<app-home [nav]="appNav"></app-home>
`

Comment: But my template is
<body>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>

Comment: and as `home` component is loading from `router-outlet` in this case, `service` is needed.  Check out my updated answer, i have give new stackblitz link .

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fy2fcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts updated link with router-outlet

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbjmgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts this link is working exactly, without service, just as first answer is as.. Go for your convenient way.. Hope helps you!!

Comment: welcome, Its always good to use service for data communication between more than two components, use @Input() and @Output for nearly one level parent-child components, and content-projection using `ng-content` used when load child component inside parent component. and use `template-outlet` for displaying different template for different needs without changing any logic inside component. Happy angular way.. :)